# JSON Script issue while executing Coded UI test using C#

Tags: c#, json, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to automated a web application , where a web form is used to save information for a specific logged-in user.
In this form few grids gather information and thus info is posted to Server as soon as the user submit's it.(Clicks on Submit button)
For this a json call is sent on the server side . I tried automating this using VSTS2012(Coded UI Test). All controls are recognizable and I am able to enter correct details. But as soon as I hit Submit button . An exception :"Error:Unable to get property 'd'of undefined or null reference" is received.

Can someone please help me understand to how to handle this?
Apart from closing the browser instance i am unable to execute my script further

Comment: is it in cristal report??\

Comment: No Abhinav. This is a .aspx web page with multiple controls , some in the form of grid other as textboxes. I am trying to automate this page using coded ui test. Now capturing these controls and entering data has been done but few grids send data to the server as soon as the submit button(from UI is clicked). Now this is happening because for this page some json scripts are written which are executed as submit button is clicked. Let me know if my comment helped you understand my query

Comment: ok. your javascript is trying to get property d of some object that is not defined. try debugging javascript and look for d.

i can say more after looking at your javascript code.

Comment: Hi Abhinav, I think i found the reason, so as these were AJAX calls and as VSTS2012 was not able to handle AJAX call but on adding following in App setting file for this project :   <appSettings>
    <add key="WebWaitForReadyLevel" value="3"/> </appSettings> .I could capture the response from the javascript. For now my issue is handled with this setting. But thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the reason, so as these were AJAX calls and as VSTS2012 was not able to handle AJAX call but on adding following in App setting file for this project :

```
 <appSettings>  
  <add key="WebWaitForReadyLevel" value="3"/>  
 </appSettings>
```

I could capture the response from the java script.